# combine two records into one

Tags: sql-server

I've looked on here and there's a number of questions involving combining two records into one, but I think mine is a unique problem. 
I have a software that uses sql queries to create desktop gadgets for our ticketing software. I want to track how many help desk tickets each technician has, and I have working code for that. It produces a bar graph that works great, however, sometimes multiple technicians or a technician and a manager are assigned to a ticket, and I can't extract that data. The code is:

```
SELECT TECHNICIAN, COUNT(TECHNICIAN) AS TICKETS
FROM TABLE
```

(there's a bit of extra complexity with an inner join so I can get the employee's name on the bar graph by linking the employee's ID to the table with their actual names, but this is the simplified version)

Here's my current result set:

```
TECHNICIAN    TICKETS
Bob           5
Bob, Harry    1
Joe           6
Mark          3
Jeff          2
```

and the result set I  WANT is:

```
TECHNICIAN    TICKETS
Bob           6
Joe           6
Mark          3
Jeff          2
```

If the result set above goes into the gadget, it makes a bar for every record. So there would be a 'bob' bar and a 'bob, harry' bar. Also, I know that I only want technicians, so I don't need it to make a separate 'harry' record, just add both 'bob's together. ALSO, I have read-only access to the database, so creating new tables to hold the data is out.

Thank you!

Comment: Your table is not well normalized. There should be two rows in another table for Bob and Harry on Ticket-1

Comment: Assuming that Harry is excluded for being a manager, how do you distinguish "Bob, Harry" (giving one for just Bob) from "Bob, Joe" (one for Bob, one for Joe)?

Comment: Also your first code sample isn't right - you must have a GROUP BY you've left out.

Comment: @codingbiz, If I had write permission to the database, I'd normalize the data

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight, There really is no good solution for that. Sometimes managers and techs bet put on one ticket, and sometimes two techs. I guess I'd like the first tech assigned to get the 'point'.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I DO have a group by in there. I just left it out of here for the sake of distilling the code to the simplest thing I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `TECHNICIAN` column is 255 characters:

```
SELECT Tech, Tickets = COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Tech = SUBSTRING
           (
              TECHNICIAN, 1, 
              COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', TECHNICIAN)-1, -1), 255)
           )
  FROM dbo.[TABLE]
) AS x
GROUP BY Tech;
```

Comment: That's great! Now the only thing is: where would I put in my statemets that nullify managers? Example:
     AND TECHNICIAN <> 'HARRY'